# Installed Ubuntu from external drive, cannot boot from internal SSD drive

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive, iso

This is my first time trying to install a Linux operating system after reading  many interesting exciting articles about it, but I really need some help!
I am trying to install ubuntu-14.04.3 onto my Toshiba satellite cl45-c4330 laptop.

I used Universal USB installer to put ubuntu-14.04.3 onto my external hard drive (I don't have a flash drive) and after changing the boot order to start from USB, I was able to start the Ubuntu installation.

However, on the third page of the installation I received this error:

```
fsyncing/closing/dev/mmcblk0rpmb: input/output error. Retry, Ignore, Cancel
```

I wasn't sure what to do at that point, so I just clicked ignore, and the rest of the installation process seemed to work just fine until the very end where it prompts a reboot. 
after rebooting, I only get a black screen with the message

```
Reboot and select proper boot device
or insert Boot media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

I made sure that I was booting from the laptop's SSD hard drive and not USB external drive, but I still get the same message. But if I try booting from the external USB drive, it just asks me if I want to install Ubuntu.

So I tried reinstalling from USB again and during the second installation attempt I got the same error on page 3:

```
fsyncing/closing/dev/mmcblk0rpmb: input/output error
```

however, on the 4th page of the installation it says `This computer currently has ubuntu-14.04.3 LTS on it. What would you like to do?`

What? So if Ubuntu is already installed on the laptop's hard drive, why wasn't it able to boot from the hard drive? I chose "erase disk and install Ubuntu" went through the installation, rebooted the laptop, and again "Reboot and select proper boot device" I'm confused... I thought maybe it was a bad download, so I tried downloading the Ubuntu ISO a second time, but no luck...

Boot repair didn't solve the problem, but here is the link to the boot info log paste.ubuntu.com/13266107

Can anyone tell me what other information I could provide to help diagnose the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: now instead of reinstall, boot from a pendrive and try [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: OK I ran boot repair, but i still got the same "Reboot and select proper boot device" on startup. here is the link to the boot info log http://paste.ubuntu.com/13266107/

Comment: https://communities.intel.com/message/266696 seems to have an answer.

Comment: It looks like you have a 320GB hard drive with the installer. Installer is normally is on a small flash drive. And Your 320GB drive was erased which the installer normally does to flash drive. And then it looks like you installed full Lubuntu to a 32GB memory card. Do you have a memory card plugged into system? Is that what you wanted to do? Does your system boot from memory cards, a few do, most need a flash drive.

Comment: Oldfred, yes I used a 320GB external hard drive as an installer as I did not have a flash drive on hand. The hard drive on my laptop is a 32GB SSD, so maybe that's why it's interpreting it as a memory card? Anyway, It's the same drive that used to have Windows 10 pre installed on it, so I don't understand why it couldn't install Ubuntu to that same drive?